# ACRA make it boring if there are many exceptions thrown

Tags: android, acra

I use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in my android application. It's very useful but sometimes boring.

Sometimes, there are several asynchronous tasks running in the background. And for season, all of them failed(e.g. can't connect to internet). ACRA will show the toast message again and again, and refused to exit.

Is it able to let ACRA just catch the first exception? Or just show the toast message once?

---

**Update**

add a demo: https://github.com/freewind/android-acra-multi-reports

There are 4 activities in this project. The last one will throw exception and each previous activity will throw exception in `onActivityResult`. You can see ACRA will report many times before exiting.

Comment: If you can build a sample project which demonstrates this behavior and file an issue on the GitHub issue tracker, I could see if something can be done to prevent it.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you, and I just add a demo.

Comment: @Freewind I don't see anything unexpected in your demo. Neither do I understand what you are trying to prove with that demo: you're throwing exceptions without catching them. If you call `startActivityForResult` and the `Activity` crashes the calling `Activity` will get a negative result. If you throw another Exception in `onActivityResult`, well then that `Activity` will of cause crash too. Also see the [doc for `Activity`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Answer (score 3):

That sounds to me like you should actually catch some exceptions and don't let all of them bubble up.

ACRA registers a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` on the main thread. Here all uncaught exceptions (as the handler's name suggests) get processed. Usually that means that the application is about to crash and ACRA will do its reporting magic. ACRA uses several Threads itself to do its work and will wait until everything is finished before it actually kills the application's process. So I'd guess that if there are coming a lot of exceptions, ACRA is just so busy to process them that it won't come to the point were it would kill the process.

You could register your own implementation of `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions and decide when to hand them through to ACRA and when to do something else. If I'm not mistaken, ACRA will call through to the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` that has been registered before the ACRA init. So you could also try to chain those handlers.

Comment: Is this supported, or a hack on ACRA?

Comment: Well, it is rather a hack. I didn't found this in a documentation, but by investigating ACRA's code and how `UncaughtExceptionHandler` works.

Comment: That's not maintainable right. They change something and your implementation goes BOOM! You'll have to change so that it keeps up with their changes.

Comment: Not necessarily. `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` is the last point where unhandled exceptions will bubble up to, to be able to react to them. Unless Android changes the way applications are executed, there shouldn't be any glitches with that. So this is the only point ACRA can be hooked up with in a meaningful way.